# How do you set Script Timeouts on Selenium Webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

There are three kinds of timeout functions for Java in [Wedriver.Timeouts](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#setScriptTimeout%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

1. implcitlyWait
2. pageLoadTimeout
3. setScriptTimeout

I'm trying to look up the python equivalent of the third, but am not able to find it. The following are the python equivalents of the first two.

1. implicitly_wait(10)
2. set_page_load_timeout(20)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
set_script_timeout(time_to_wait)

    Set the amount of time that the script should wait during an
        execute_async_script call before throwing an error.

    Args :  

        time_to_wait: The amount of time to wait (in seconds)

    Usage : 

    driver.set_script_timeout(30)
```

Ref - [set_script_timeout](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_script_timeout)